# how to convert paramater date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, momentjs

I have a value `this.birthday` which containes this value `Mon Aug 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)T00:00:00-00:00`

my birthday model receives this value even tho' my datepicker is configured like so...

```
<el-date-picker v-model="birthday" v-validate="'required|date_format:YYYY-MM-DD'" type="date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" :picker-options="pickerOptions1"></el-date-picker>
```

How can I use **moment.js** to convert this date value to `YYYY-MM-DD` ?

I'm trying to manipulate the date value held inside birthday to my desired output....but I have no clue how. None of the documentation seems to be helping.

```
onSubmitted() {
  axios.post(`${process.env.KITTY_URL}/api/v1/cats/`, {
    name: this.name,
    age: this.age,
    gender: this.gender,
    cat_type: this.cat_type,
    litter_mates: this.litter_mates,
    weight: this.weight,
    birthday: moment(this.birthday.toString()).format('DD-MM-YYYY'),<---?????? what should this be???
    weight_unit: this.weight_unit
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      response.status === 201 ? this.showSuccess = true : this.showDanger = true
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.showDanger = true;
    })
}
```

Comment: You can try  this `moment().format("MMM Do YY")`

Comment: If you try this `moment('Mon Aug 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)T00:00:00-00:00')._isValid` you will get `false`, this means the date string you supplied is invalid. Try using one of the well-known DateTime formats.

Comment: Ikbel...that string is what gets output to my v-modal birthday....I see that value when I do an inspect / Network / params in my browser.

Comment: @Jessi Yes, I've just noticed that when I tried to test that date picker, so it's basically returning a Date object already, which means you can just remove the `toString()` part and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `el-date-picker` is already setting a `Date` object to `birthday`. To convert it to a formatted string, just use the following and it should work.

```
moment(this.birthday).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: yep, tried that one...for some strange reason it did not work...I did find a solution tho'....I'll post it in a moment

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I found....looking into the internet I found this random page....https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker

within it was a clue..

```
// ...
options: {
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  useCurrent: false,
}
```

this seemed to be the key. my `birthday` param now receives the correct format.